# Android current location in maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display current location in google maps in android and it shows error while test the app on actual device not on emulator. The error is-

```
The client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to st HIGH_ACCURACY priority
```

[image]

Comment: The error says clearly that you are missing a permission. and it even says which! what is your problem?

Comment: you need to add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to your manifest! Pay atention to your log please

Answer (score 1):

Please add this line to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also, is clear what the log says. Read a little more about android permissions.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html